# PowerMockito verify a arbitrary number param constructor call

Tags: java, constructor, mockito, powermock

I want to check that a specific constructor is called with a certain set of params and to check that the params are correct.

The class uses the arbitrary parameters of java ( ... ) like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    public MyClass(Object o, int... params){
        //DOSOMETHING   
    }
}
```

The class under test has a method that do this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) @PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class ClassUnderTest {
    private int[] par;
    public ClassUnderTest(int... params){
        this.par = params;
    }

    public MyClass methodToTest(){
        return new MyClass(null, this.par);
    }
}
```

I want to check that the returned MyClass was actually called with the correct agruments.

What I did is this:

```
whenNew(MyClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(null);

ClassUnderTest clazz = new ClassUnderTest(0, 1, 2);
MyClass res = clazz.methodToTest();
verifyNew(MyClass.class).withArguments(eq(null), any(int[].class));
```

But is not working with this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Wanted but not invoked my.package.MyClass(
    null,
    <any>
);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Do you have any suggestion or Idea how to test this, I would like to avoid using getters of MyClass.....

Comment: May I ask **why** you would like to avoid simply checking the state of MyClass after creating it? The whole thing looks pretty simply, only that requirements leads you to needing PowerMockito at all... (and it tends to be a solution for problems you do not need to have).

Comment: I thought that this should work: `verifyNew(MyClass.class).withArguments(eq(null), Matchers.<Integer>anyVararg());` , but neither. Probably it's a bug... Just as a couriosity, altought it doesn't answer your question at all, this works: `verifyNew(MyClass.class).withArguments(eq(null), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt());`. I'll be waiting for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem just PreparingForTest the class that I was testing so I did:

```
@PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)
```

instead of

```
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
```

Monday if I'll have some spare time I will post a more detailed answer

Comment: That monday did not come :)